# Fragment to Fragment Interface error (layout)

Tags: android, interface

I'm sending an interface from Fragment 5 to 3 through the main activity :

```
public void setF3Riddle(int x) {

  Frag3 F3 = (Frag3) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Frag3);

  if (F3 != null) {
     F3.getF3Riddle(x);
  } else {
     Frag3 frag = new Frag3();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("Value", x);
     frag.setArguments(args);
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.Frag3, frag)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
     frag.getF3Riddle(x);
  }
}
```

But it crashes when I send the data while running. I've noticed the problem when I change the `.replace(R.id.Frag3,Frag)` container to another fragment it doesn't crash. What's the problem here?

Fragment 3 Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Frag3"
    tools:context="com.redot.puzzle3.Frag3">
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is from here:

```
Frag3 frag = new Frag3();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("Value", x);
frag.setArguments(args);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.Frag3, frag)
                           .addToBackStack(null)
                           .commit();
frag.getF3Riddle(x);
```

You're creating the fragment with `Frag3 frag = new Frag3();` and put the bundle then you want to get the value with `frag.getF3Riddle(x)`. But it will throw an error because the the fragment is not yet finished created. Fragment creation is **asynchronous** process. So, you need to wait until the frag is finished created or create it in another place first.

Comment: 3 already exist and I've done the same thing with fragment 4 and it worked. I think the problem is with the layout because when I replace the fragment id `R.id.Frag3` with Frag4 and it doesnt crash it just replaces the fragment 4 I want it to replace frament 3 but for some reason it crashes